# X-Frame-Options to support different subdomain of same domain

Tags: java, apache, iframe, http-headers

I want to know whether it's possible to support X-Frame-Options for a different subdomain of same domain.

Comment: i have answered with other people to a question like yours it [stackoverflow here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)

Comment: @ArthurTsidkilov this is a different question. The question you linked asks about framing other sites. This question is about whether a mismatch only in subdomain will be allowed by x-frame-options (I'm assuming by using "X-Frame-Options: sameorigin")

Answer (score 0):

Two URLs have the same origin, if and only if, they have identical schemes (protocols), hostnames, and ports. So a domain and its subdomain have different origins.

With old browsers, it was possible to use an [X-FRAME-OPTIONS HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), such as:

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM <origin>
```

but this is no more supported by modern browsers. See [X-Frame-Options HTTP header on caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=X-FRAME-OPTIONSX-Frame-Options).

With modern browsers, you can use either:

```
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

to deny all framing, or:

```
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

to allow framing from the same origin.

To allow framing from a different origin, you now have to use the [frame-ancestors CSP directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) such as:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors https://sub1.ex.com https://sub2.ex.com;
```

Note that if both a frame-ancestors CSP directive and a `X-Frame-Options: DENY` header is present, the CSP directive takes precedence, as defined in the [HTML living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/document-lifecycle.html#the-x-frame-options-header).